# Loading dictionary using trie in C very slow with large data set

Tags: performance, c, trie

The code below works for very small dictionary files I used to test (two words).  However when I run this using a more typical dictionary file, my machine slows to the point of near crash.  I would like a review of what the potential bottleneck may be which I believe to be in the `load()` function. Of course, general comments are also welcomed if they may help with optimization and overall performance.

```
typedef struct node

{
    bool is_word;
    struct node* children[27];
} 
node;

node* root;

int nwords = 0;

/**
* Returns true if word is in dictionary else false.
*/

bool check(const char* word)
{
    node* current = root;

    int i = 0;

    while(word[i] != '\0')
    {
        int letter = tolower(word[i]);

        if (letter == '\'')
        {
            return false;
        }    

        if (current->children[letter-'a'] != NULL)
        {
            current = current->children[letter-'a'];
            i++;
        }

        else
        {
           return false;
        }
    }

    if (current->is_word == true)
    {
       return true;

    }

    return false;
 }


/**
 * Loads dictionary into memory.  Returns true if successful else false.
*/

bool load(const char* dictionary)
{

    FILE* dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");

    if(dict == false)
    {
       return false;
    }    

    //initialize nodes

    root = calloc(27,sizeof(node)); 
    node* current = NULL;

    int c = 0;

    while(fgetc(dict) != EOF)
   {
       fseek(dict, -1, SEEK_CUR); //go back one byte to beginning of word
       current = root; //set index to root

       for(c = fgetc(dict); c != '\n'; c = fgetc(dict)) //iterate through word
       {
            if(current->children[c-'a'] == NULL)
            {
                current->children[c-'a'] = calloc(27,sizeof(node));
                current = current->children[c-'a'];
            }
            else
            {
                current = current->children[c-'a'];
            }       
        }
        current->is_word = true; //once line break reached end the word
        nwords++;
    }    

    fclose(dict);
    return true;    
}

/**
* Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded.
*/

unsigned int size(void)
{
    return nwords;
}


/**
 * Unloads dictionary from memory.  Returns true if successful else false.
 */

void freeNode(node* current)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        if(current->children[i] != NULL)
        {
            freeNode(current->children[i]);
        }
    }
    free(current);
}    

bool unload(void)
{
    freeNode(root);  
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It would be a whole lot easier to profile your code for the bottleneck if you included *everything* and not just this little bit.

Comment: Notice that you calloc(27,sizeof(node)) to add a tree element, which allocates 27*sizeof(node), so each node takes 27x as much space as you need.  try calloc(1,sizeof(node)) instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few notes:

- `typedef struct` names are commonly written in [PascalCase](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PascalCase) today.

  ```
  Node* current = NULL;
  ```
- Initialize your variables on the lowest scope as possible.  Therefore, declare your variables within your `for` loops. <sup>(C99)</sup>

  ```
  for(int c = fgetc(dict); c != '\n'; c = fgetc(dict)) //iterate through word
  ```

  Also, I feel as if you should be checking `c` for `EOF`, and then check for `\n` within the `for` loop.
- The statements inside of your `for` loop look fishy to me:

  ```
  if(current->children[c-'a'] == NULL)
  {
      current->children[c-'a'] = calloc(27,sizeof(node))
      current = current->children[c-'a'];
  }
  else
  {                
      current = current->children[c-'a'];
  }
  ```

  No matter what, you are going to set `children` equal to `current->children[c-'a']`, so you can move that statement out of both branches of the conditional ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)). Also, you should not be allocating 27 elements for every single `Node`.  Here is how I would write it:

  ```
  if (!current->children[c-'a']) current->children[c-'a'] = calloc(1, sizeof(node));
  current = current->children[c-'a'];
  ```
- You can remove the `!= NULL` part in your `if` conditional statements.
- [Avoid global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/485020/1937270): `root` and `nwords`.
- Avoid [magic numbers](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMagic_number_(programming)&ei=9sDaU-vrEoKyyATChYHoBw&usg=AFQjCNEBrhFvMq4tSp1fmTLhIkLF2eIkMw&sig2=1vWHoIe0UikYI2TwyLf9Gg&bvm=bv.72185853,d.aWw).

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
  ```

  Use a `#define` instead at the top of your code.

  ```
  #define NUM_NODES 27
  ```

  But where does the number 27 even come from?  Documentation would go a long way here to help developers understand what it is.
- Set your `Node` values to `NULL` after you free them.  This is so that you do not try to access the data again after it has been freed.

Comment: thanks.  I replace the if statement with your and it blazes through now.  Can you please elaborate on why I did not need the `else` portion (i.e., if the node is null)?  Also I think the apostrophe escaping was correct.  There are other bugs in the `check` function I need to sort out though.

Comment: @Andy I edited in an explanation, though I am surprised that one replacement made it so much more efficient.  Did you have compiler optimizations disabled?

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Yes, I first took out the `fseek` which got the program to stop crashing but average load time of 1400K word dictionary was 4 seconds and with your if/else edit time is 0.03 seconds.  Oddly, and I need to investigate, with your edit the `unload` time fell considerably.  Perhaps what I was doing earlier was creating superfluous nodes.  In any event, thanks.

Comment: @Andy No, by not setting the `Node` values to `NULL`, you were performing excessive recursive calls on the children to free them.

Comment: You probably should check isalpha(letter) rather than the apostrophe check, to avoid any non-letter (as you rely on that for the array index/offset anyway.

Answer (score 7):

IO is most likely your problem. The `fseek(dict, -1, ...)` is performing unnecessary IO. If you restructure your loop to be more efficient, it will help...

Consider this loop:

```
int c = 0;

// note, store the c on this read....
while((c = fgetc(dict)) != EOF)
{
   if (c == '\n')
   {
      // end of word, save it....
      if (!current->is_word)
      {
          //in case of duplicates.
          current->is_word = true; //once line break reached end the word
          nwords++;
      }
      // reset the pointers.
      current = root;
   } else {
        if(current->children[c-'a'] == NULL)
        {
            current->children[c-'a'] = calloc(27,sizeof(node));
        }       
        current = current->children[c-'a'];
   }
}    
if (current!= root && !current->is_word)
{
    //in case of duplicates, and an unterminated last line.
    current->is_word = true; //once line break reached end the word
    nwords++;
}
```

Doing it this way ensures a forward-only scan through the file.

Comment: I removed the `fseek` and now it at least runs to completion although I think check may have a bug I need to sort out.  Interestingly the slowest part of program is the recursive `unload()` function.  Of 3.75 seconds of run time, 2.73 are in `unload`.

Comment: fgets and read a whole line/word, chomp the newline, and add a word at a time.

Answer (score 5):

You are allocating a lot of space (and much of it is wasted). Grabbing memory affects performance in various ways, most important being a cache performance. And with the links pointing all over the memory space, cache misses incur serious cost over tree traversal.

Bottomline is, do not expect a good performance from a tree with high branghing factor. Take a look at a [PATRICIA (or radix)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) tree for a correct implementation of your idea.

PS: My two cents in addition to @syb0rg analysis: using fseek restricts you from the streaming files, and strictly speaking it is not necessary at all:

```
while((c = fgetc(dict)) != EOF) {
    current = root; //set index to root

    for(; c != '\n'; c = fgetc(dict)) //iterate through word
    {
        ...
    }
```

  -

Answer (score 5):

I was curious about the performance of a trie so did a few tests to satisfy myself. First two problems with your original code:

1. You don't check for EOF in your inner for loop meaning your code will run forever unless the file ends exactly with a `\n`.

   ```
   for(c = fgetc(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = fgetc(dict)) //iterate through word
   ```

   Always check return codes when reading data from files. I suspect this may be the issue with your code "crashing" as even with loading 150k words your code only takes 1.5 seconds with the fix.
2. Another issue is the mixing of `fopen(..., "r")` with `fseek()` depending on if your word file contains `\n` or `\r\n` line terminations. Using mode `r` with `\n` will probably result in incorrect parsing when seeking...at least it did with me using VS2010 on Windows7 causing considerable head scratching. Changing the mode to `rb` fixed the seek issue but eliminating the seek altogether is a better fix and then the file mode doesn't matter.

The other answers go over a variety of good optimizations and code improvements but I wanted to look specifically at how each one impacts the performance of the loading code (Note: please take the times below with a grain of salt...do your own benchmarks if performance really matters):

1. Your original code (with the two fixes mentioned above) takes **1500ms** to load/parse 150k english words. Not necessarily bad. It results in 388k allocations of new nodes.
2. Removing the `fseek()` call reduces this to **1060ms**.
3. Loading the file all at once (only 1.5MB) and parsing the string using `strtok()` has a very small performance increase to **1000 ms**.
4. Replacing the `strtok()` with manual parsing logic has no visible effect.
5. At this point the only obvious thing left is to optimize the individual allocations with one block allocation (see code at the end). This has a huge effect on performance reducing the loading time to only **15 ms**. Hopefully that is fast enough for you....
6. At this point there isn't anything obvious left to optimize. You could try saving and loading the completely parsed trie but the I'm not sure if you'd gain much with the larger read size involved. Profiling would be your best bet to see what, if anything, could be optimized.

Note that the code below is missing some error handling/checking code for simplicity and the node allocation size is hard coded for the same reason. Look up "block/bucket/arena allocators" for more details on this type of optimization.

```
         // Loads 150k word dictionary in 15ms (x100 faster than original implementation)
bool loadfaster(const char* dictionary)
{
        // Size is hard coded for this example code (388k allocations used)
        // You'd also want to be able to free() the memory some how
    node* pNodeBucket = calloc(400000, sizeof(node));
    node* pNextFreeNode = pNodeBucket;

    FILE* dict = fopen(dictionary, "rb");  // "b" mode is important here
    if(dict == false) return false;

        // Get size of file: should check for error codes here
    fseek(dict, 0, SEEK_END);
    long Size = ftell(dict);
    fseek(dict, 0, SEEK_SET);

        // Read entire file: should check for read error here
    char* pBuffer = malloc(Size + 1);
    fread(pBuffer, 1, Size, dict);
    fclose(dict);

        // File data will not be nul terminated when read
    pBuffer[Size] = '\0';

    root = pNextFreeNode++;
    node* current = NULL;

    int c = 0;
    char* pParse = pBuffer;

    while (*pParse)
    {
        current = root;

       for(; *pParse != '\n' && *pParse; ++pParse)
       {
            if(current->children[*pParse-'a'] == NULL)
            {
                current->children[*pParse-'a'] = pNextFreeNode++;
            }

            current = current->children[*pParse-'a'];
        }

        current->is_word = true;
        nwords++;

        if (*pParse == '\n') ++pParse;
    }

    free(pBuffer);
    return true;    
}
```

**Update on `unload()`:**
I missed that your were also looking at the performance of the `unload()` function. Unfortunately, if you keep the original allocation scheme there isn't very much you can do. Memory allocation/deallocation can be slow and with not always consistent (it can take longer or shorter depending on the state of the allocator).

For example, in my sample test of 150k words `unload()` has to check 10.5 million pointers and deallocate 388k of them taking 7 seconds to do so (would be faster if not running under VS). If you change the allocator to a single bucket as in my example then your deallocation is simply:

```
          // Make pNodeBucket global for this to work
 void unloadfaster()
 {
      free(pNodeBucket);
 }
```

Which should be negligible in general (not visible in my simple time tests).

Comment: this is great analysis.  Am going to try this as well.  And yes, 15ms is fast enough, lol.  I originally did this in PHP and it took like 20 seconds!

Answer (score 2):

ChuckCottril and vnp are way right. Furthermore, below the first 2-3 layers of the trie, nearly every node is 26/27 full of NULL pointers, so that's another factor of 27 wasted storage. (27*27 = 729x wasted storage.)

What I would do is:

1. Put the words in a long ordered array.
   (The size of this is a tiny fraction of an equivalent trie.)
2. Only use the trie for sufficient levels to be an index into that array.
   The way to build it is to recursively walk the ordered array, building the trie on the way out.

In terms of performance, memory allocation is a *huge* killer.

ADDED: uesp also has a good idea, which is to do only one `calloc` rather than many.
The way to do this is to walk the ordered word list twice.
First you walk it to see how much storage you need (this is very fast).
Then you `calloc` the storage.
Finally you walk it again, building the trie by personally allocating nodes out of the block you got with `calloc`.

Comment: For some reason I thought when I create a new node that new node has to have a spot for every letter in alphabet. But I guess that is done in the struct's definition.  Might explain why `unload` was so brutally slow.

Comment: @Andy: right, but the "spot" is a pointer to a node, not a whole node, as ChuckCottril pointed out. Plus, below the first 2-3 levels, very few nodes contain >1 pointer, because most words contain many more letters than are needed to disambiguate them. Look at any dictionary and see how many initial letters are in common between adjacent words. Or type something into Google and see how quickly it guesses what you wanted.